# Are inferred types reflected in byte code?

Tags: java, type-inference, type-erasure

I am aware of type inference and type erasure in Java, but I am unsure about how they work. Say `List<Integer> list = List.of(1)`  for instance. Since `of(E... elements)` takes in a variable number of some type of elements and returns `List<E>`, I suppose that `E` is inferred to be Integer.

The part that I am confused about is that since `E` is already inferred to be `Integer`, does `E` still erases to `Object` after type erasure at compile-time? How does Type erasure work and what is the significance of type inference if the inferred types are not "stored"/"carried forward"?

Comment: I'm not understanding your last question. What is the significance of _what_?

Comment: The inferred types are used to check your program for type errors, and then discarded.

Comment: @Sweeper, I've edited it. I wanted to ask about the significance of type inference because I was curious about the point of inferring types if type inference is not carried forward. Sorry if it was confusing, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @LouisWasserman, thanks I appreciate it! Things are making sense now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when compile, generics create only one specialization, using Object, let's say that you have two list `List<? extends Object> list = List.of(1)` and `List<? extends Object> strs = List.of("test")`, in compile time both will be a `List<Object>`, for second question, type erasure is good for reducing code footprint, with only one specialization, and it reduces the memory cost of carry this information, important too talk about don't allow reflection abuses, if we carry these information it would allow a lot of things that could make the program not reasonable. And erasure of course gives the ability to compatibly evolve a class from non-generic to generic, without breaking existing sources or binary class files.

Comment: That was really comprehensive, I appreciate it. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: my bad, upvoted!